Huggingface trainer is not showing any progress for finetuning
I have a dataset I want to fine-tune a huggingface LLM with.
This dataset is quite simple. It has two columns: one column has DNA sequences (each in the form of a string 5000 letters long). Another column has a binary label. My dataset is only 240 rows long.
For some reason, the trainer.train() step is not making any progress.
I have access to 2 a100 GPUs, so I don't think it's a computational resource issue.
Here I'm loading in the data and tokenizing the sequences.
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df[['sequence', 'label']]) 

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-v2-500m-multi-species", trust_remote_code=True)

def tokenize_function(examples):
    outputs = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(examples["sequence"], return_tensors="pt", truncation="longest_first", padding='max_length', 
                                          max_length=836)
    return outputs
    
# Creating tokenized  dataset
tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(
    tokenize_function,
    batched=True, batch_size=2048)

Here I'm reducing the parameters of the model:
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-v2-500m-multi-species", num_labels=2, trust_remote_code=True)

peft_config = LoraConfig(
    task_type=TaskType.SEQ_CLS, inference_mode=False, r=1, lora_alpha= 32, lora_dropout=0.1, target_modules= ["query", "value"])

lora_classifier = get_peft_model(model, peft_config) # transform our classifier into a peft model
lora_classifier.print_trainable_parameters()

lora_classifier = nn.DataParallel(lora_classifier, device_ids=[0, 1])
lora_classifier = lora_classifier.to("cuda:0")

Here I'm prepping for training:
args_ = TrainingArguments(
    "finetuned_NT",
    remove_unused_columns=False,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    save_strategy="steps",
    learning_rate=5e-4,
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    gradient_accumulation_steps= 1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size= 32,
    eval_steps=10,
    logging_steps= 10, 
    load_best_model_at_end=True,  # Keep the best model according to the evaluation
    metric_for_best_model="ROC-AUC", # The mcc_score on the evaluation dataset used to select the best model
    label_names=["label"],
    dataloader_drop_last=True,
    max_steps= 10
)

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    # get predictions
    predictions, labels = eval_pred
    # apply softmax to get probabilities
    probabilities = np.exp(predictions) / np.exp(predictions).sum(-1,
                keepdims=True)
    # use probabilities of the positive class for ROC AUC
    positive_class_probs = probabilities[:, 1]
    # compute auc
    auc = np.round(auc_score.compute(prediction_scores=positive_class_probs,
            references=labels)['roc_auc'],3)
    # predict most probable class
    predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
    # compute accuracy
    acc = np.round(accuracy.compute(predictions=predicted_classes,
            references=labels)['accuracy'],3)
    return {"Accuracy": acc, "ROC-AUC": auc}

Splitting data:
train_test_split = tokenized_dataset.select_columns(['label', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask']).train_test_split(test_size=0.2, seed=42)

# Now split the test set into test (50%) and validation (50%)
test_val_split = train_test_split['test'].train_test_split(test_size=0.5, seed=42)

# Combine the splits into a DatasetDict
final_split = DatasetDict({
    'train': train_test_split['train'],
    
    'test': test_val_split['train'],
    'validation': test_val_split['test']
})

trainer = Trainer(
    model=lora_classifier,  # Assuming `lora_classifier` is your model
    args=args_,  # Make sure `args_` contains the correct training arguments
    train_dataset=final_split['train'],  # Train dataset from the split
    eval_dataset=final_split['validation'],  # Validation dataset from the split
    tokenizer=tokenizer,  # Tokenizer used for preprocessing
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics  # Metric computation function, assuming `compute_metrics_mcc` is defined
)

When I run trainier.train(), no progress bar comes up, no logs come up (I tried waiting for hours). It says like this with no change.
/sc/arion/work/test-env/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/optimization.py:306: FutureWarning: This implementation of AdamW is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use the PyTorch implementation torch.optim.AdamW instead, or set `no_deprecation_warning=True` to disable this warning
  warnings.warn(
***** Running training *****
  Num examples = 192
  Num Epochs = 4
  Instantaneous batch size per device = 32
  Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 64
  Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
  Total optimization steps = 10
  Number of trainable parameters = 1170434


